# Unable to renew apple developer program

Tags: ios, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

I am trying to renew my apple developer program but am unable to renew it. Previously I used to see the renew button in developer.apple.com itself now I don't see that instead it says download the Apple Developer app on iPhone or iPad and renew (as shown in attached screenshot). When I tried to renew it from that app on iPad I get an error saying "Your Purchase could not be completed".

Things already tried

- Signing out from the device and signing in again
- Removing the payment method and re-adding it

None of the things worked. Any idea how to renew the membership

[image]

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: @HarrySharma yes , ill post it as the answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two ways

1. Contact apple support through their chat support and they will make some changes on their end then the option(renew button) is visible after 24 hours - this is the preferred solution but you will have to wait for 24 hours.
2. Do a inspect element on that page and you can see the renew button as hidden, change the property hidden to false, and try renewing the membership

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got from apple

Hi xxx,

My name is xxx from Apple Developer Program Support. I am happy to help you today.

I understand you are contacting us about renewing your individual membership.

When you signed up for the Apple Developer Program last year you used an iOS or Mac device. This device was signed to the App Store with a different Apple ID to the one you used for the Apple Developer Program.

To renew your account you must use the same Apple ID that was signed into the App Store, this is why you are unable to renew your account at this time. For account security and data protection I am unable to provide this information.

Please try to locate the device you used last year to purchase your developer program. Under that Apple ID you should find the option to renew your account in Subscription in the Settings menu.

If you are still unable to locate the Apple ID linked to the purchase please follow the steps below:

1. Search your email for the words “invoice from Apple.”
2. On the receipt for the subscription, check which Apple ID was used.

Additionally, I would recommend you contact family or colleagues to ensure they did not use their Apple ID account to submit the subscription purchase on your behalf.

Your case number is xxxxxxxx.

Thank you for your cooperation, and I wish you a really nice day.

Best regards,

xxx

Apple Inc.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023 Dec, if you don't see any renew button which means you have turned on the auto renew check box when signing in. So you could simply add money to apple account after the subscription ends and it will automatically get added to the subscription.

Got to App Store -> Account Setting (Top right) -> Add funds;

Add the fund required for the subscription and instantly it will get added to the account and then the renewal be done automatically by apple, I dont know why there are no docs for this, spend 5 days to find this.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem above, expired membership and can't see the renew button - not in the developer app, no where on the website. (I thought I was on auto renew - as my last year's invoice said it was an auto renew payment).

Tried everything - could not see the auto renew button at all. So @Abinvs answer helped. You can renew subscriptions inside the App Store.

Simply open App Store and click on the account in top right. I went to subscriptions and so my expired developer subscription, simply clicked on it and re-purchased it. Does the regular bank stuff, but payment went through and my membership was immediately restarted!

So a slight variation to the other answer which I am sure will work too. Big big thanks for pointing me in the right direction Abin vs!

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me too Just add money into your wallet it would be auto renewed in a minute