# Apple developer Renew membership button is not showing in India country

Tags: ios, developer-tools, apple-developer, apple-developer-account, apple-developer-enterprise

I don't know what was going.
Last year (2022) I found the renew button in Developer app on Mac and renewed on time.

But, Now 2023/2024 - Renew button in Developer app not showing. Even though my membership was expired on Dec 16, 2023.

But, No Renew button. Help me folks, I need to renew my account. How to do it.

> If I add fund Rs. 8700/- means to Apple Account. What will happened?
> Auto renew will apply or not?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to renew apple developer program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73007597/unable-to-renew-apple-developer-program)

Comment: Also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77646635/no-option-to-renew-membership-of-my-already-live-app-in-apple-developer-program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked with Apple Support Team and found the solution of this problem.

If Renew button is not visible in Apple Developer app (OR) Membership program subscription was expired. Means just try few steps below.

Follow the Steps:

1. Goto MacBook Settings and Logout all your Apple ID's
2. Login on Apple ID. Which account you are going to Enroll / Renew.
3. In AppStore app Login with same Apple ID.
4. Tap the Account name on bottom left of AppStore Screen.
5. Tap Account settings on top right of AppStore Screen.
6. Scroll down to Manage section and tap Manage button of Subscription details. (Like Subscription: 0)
7. Now you see your Apple Developer Program Membership Details. Tap the Edit button.
8. In The Edit Subscription page tap the Cancel Subscription Button and proceed.
9. That's all. Now you add your fund to Apple Account and subscribe here.

It's working Fine for me.

Comment: This is the solution that also works for me. Apple should tell people how to do it